# How to Index a JOIN result of two or more tables in order to improve the performance in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, index

I am new to indexing and gone through the basics of indexing. I can find a default clustered index for the primary key constraint within the indexes part of the corresponding table, but after creating a foreign key constraint i can't find any.

Now i've a requirement in which indexing should be implemented to improve performance. I've read about **indexing the foreign key** in order to improve the performance of a **JOIN result**.

**Do i need to add the foreign key column to an additional non-clustered index or the foreign key has a default indexing?**

How can i effectively implement indexing if my **SQL table structure** is as follows and i've a **JOIN query** with **WHERE clause** using **t1_col3**

```
               table1                       table2
               ------                       ------
               t1_col1(pk)                  t2_col1(pk)
               t1_col2                      t2_col2
               t1_col3                      t2_col3
               t1_col4                      t2_col4
               t2_col1(FK)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A foreign key does not have an index by default. You have to create one.

In this case, I'd suggest either of these. It depends on relative selectivity of the 2 columns

```
CREATE INDEX IX_table2fk ON
              table1 (t2_col1, t1_col3)
              INCLUDE (any columns needed for the query)
```

OR

```
CREATE INDEX IX_table2fk ON
              table1 (t1_col3, t2_col1)
              INCLUDE (any columns needed for the query)
```

The INCLUDE will make the [index covering](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) to avoid key/bookmark lookups

Comment: Include was new feature in SQL-Server 2005. Just in case you are still on Sql-server 2000.

Comment: @bernd_k: Only 6 years and 3 versions ago :-)